# Validate a string against an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have a string like this:

```
array_string="a b"
```

I have an array like this:

```
array=(a b c)
```

I want to verify that all the elements of array_string are included in array if so I can overwrite the array with the element included in the array_string:

```
array=($array_string)
```

Which is the best way to do such a validation?

Comment: There's no built-in operation for this. You'll need to convert `array_string` to an array, then use nested loops to test if they're all in `array`.

Comment: bash has no operator to test if a string is in an array. If you need complex array operations like this frequently, `bash` is not the right language to use.

Comment: Why is `array_string` expected to contain multiple words but stored in a variable? What if one of the word contains spaces? This design itself is flawed. You should be maintaining two separate arrays

Comment: @Inian the array string is passed as an environment variable. This is a requirement I can't change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the items which exist in the `array_string` but don't exist in the `array` like this:

```
join -v1 <(sort -b <<< "${array_string// /$'\n'}") <(IFS=$'\n'; sort -b <<< "${array[*]}")
```

with the assumption that items don't contain spaces.
Using this, you can do:

```
if [[ -z $(join -v1 <(sort -b <<< "${array_string// /$'\n'}") <(IFS=$'\n'; sort -b <<< "${array[*]}")) ]]
then
    echo "array_string is a subset of array"
else
    echo "array_string is NOT a subset of array"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `grep` with couple of process substitutions:

```
grep -qvf <(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}") <(echo "${array_string// /$'\n'}") ||
echo "all elements of array_string are present in array"
```

Answer (score 2):

For string-to-array comparison the following example uses space as the separator and expects it to be at the start and end of the list so that every value will be wrapped between two separators. It also avoids using an external process or subshell.

```
for ((index=0; index < "$((${#array[@]}"; index++)); do
  if [[ "$array_string" != *" ${array[$index]} "* ]]; then
    return 1
  fi
done
```

For an array-to-array comparison it's easy to convert the string to an array after removing the leading separator, and then use a nested loop to compare them. This can also avoid using an external process or subshell as read is a [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

```
# Needs to read to a different variable so it
#   doesn't empty the source and read nothing.
IFS=' ' read -ra string_array <<< "${array_string# }"
found=1
for ((x=0; x < "${#string_array[@]}"; x++)); do
  for ((y=0; y < "${#array[@]}"; y++)); do
    if [[ "${string_array[$x]}" == "${array[$y]}" ]]; then
      found=0
    fi
  done

  if [[ found -ne 0 ]]; then
    return 1
  fi

  found=1
done
```